# Why empty query not working in SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin

When I submit the empty query in SearchView the callback not work.

When I submit a empty query, I verify if the query is empty and than return a standard response. But the problem is that it’s not working, the onQueryTextSubmit callback of OnQueryTextListener isn’t executed when the query is empty.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

By default, the SearchView won't submit an empty query, so the onQueryTextSubmit callback won't be triggered. To handle the case of an empty query being submitted, you can override the onQueryTextSubmit method of the OnQueryTextListener interface and manually trigger the callback with an empty query string.

Here's an example implementation of the onQueryTextSubmit method that handles an empty query:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (query.isEmpty()) {
        // handle empty query
        return true; // consume the event
    } else {
        // handle non-empty query
        return false; // do not consume the event
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // handle query text change
    return false;
}
});
```

In the above code, if the query string is empty, the onQueryTextSubmit method returns true to consume the event and prevent the default behavior of the SearchView. If the query string is non-empty, the method returns false to allow the default behavior to proceed.

Comment: I am not returning the true inside the if body. Maybe this is the problem. Thanks man.

Comment: When the query is empty, the onQueryTextSubmit method is not called